# Interfaces as return type

Tags: c#, interface

I couldn't understand how a method can return an object of interface and how it's parameter can be interface, like this method:

```
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddJsonFile(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, IFileProvider provider);
```

Can any one provide a simple example to demonstrate this?

Comment: it means it returns an object that implements that interface, likewise it accepts as a paramter an object that implements that interface

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Do you understand what in interface is, and how they are used?

Comment: do you mean it return an object of a class that inherit from that interface @ Jonathon Reinhart

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here, particularly because you ask for an example right after...giving an example.  Is it that you don't understand what it means for a method to return an interface type, or what interface type a method could possible return when it already accepts a parameter of the same interface?

Comment: @BACON I don't understand what it means for a method to return an interface type

Comment: You should start learning about interface, loosely coupled classes, DI and IOC.

Comment: @MahmoudAdel , yes i mean its an instance of a class that implements ('inherits from' is not really the correct term) that interface

Answer (score 1):

The return type is `IConfigurationBuilder`. In this case that simply means the returned object will be anything that explicitly implements that interface. By this I mean that the return object must be defined as something like:

```
public class MyConfigurationBuilder : IConfigurationBuilder
{
    ... Required methods go here ...
}
```

The object could also implement other interfaces, have base classes, etc, as long as it also specifically and explicitly implements the required interface. This allows the calling method to have no other expectations about the object other than it provides the methods required by that particular interface.

Comment: it's ok but how it works when I Provide a parameter to a method of type interface and I don't implement this interface as the example above  
        AddJsonFile( IFileProvider provider);

Comment: @MahmoudAdel if you don't implement the interface, the code won't compile